# DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek returns wrong day

Tags: .net

I have a windows computer with following region settings:
Home location: **Germany**,
Region format: **US**,
Windows display language: **English**,
And first day of week is **Monday**.

And this core return me wrong first day of the week.

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var test = culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek; //'Monday', but should be 'Sunday'
Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
```

Another computers have the region settings with Germany language and format, and return **Sunday**.

Comment: I see the exact opposite. For `en-US` it's Sunday, for `de-DE` it's Monday

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos var cultureEn = new CultureInfo("en-US"); //Sunday, var cultureDe = new CultureInfo("de-DE");//Monday. But with this region settings in the windows I get always 'Monday'

Comment: The OS setting overrides the .NET default.  Use Control Panel > Region > Formats tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor will use the local machine's settings if they match the culture. This can be overriden.

From the [CultureInfo(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_CultureInfo__ctor_System_String_) documentation:

> The user might choose to override some of the values associated with the current culture of Windows through the regional and language options portion of Control Panel. For example, the user might choose to display the date in a different format or to use a currency other than the default for the culture.
>
> If the culture identifier associated with name matches the culture identifier of the current Windows culture, this constructor creates a CultureInfo object that uses those overrides ...

The [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,325) shows that `CultureInfo(string)` calls the [CultureInfo(string,bool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Globalization_CultureInfo__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) constructor with the `useUserOverride` parameter set to true.

To ignore the local changes, use the same constructor with `useUserOverride` set to  `false`, eg:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US",false);
```

You can check the [CultureInfo.UseUserOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.useuseroverride?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to see whether the `CultureInfo` object you got is based on user overrides or not.

This isn't a bad design by the way. In a desktop application, the user *expects* the application to honour the locale settings.